# MySQL regular expression operations

Tags: mysql, regex

**The set-up**

A mysql table called "mytable" has a VARCHAR field "data".

The field contains a string in the format of:

```
name1'value1''name2'value2'' ... nameN''valueN
```

*I'm aware this data is denormalized -- I've been forced to use ' as the delimited since this is the only character that is not allowed as a name or value.*

Here are some example data:

```
one'.6332''two'.4231''three'.343''four'.034
two'.4332''four'.033''five'.043
four'.2323''seven'.3409''nine'.003
```

**The problem**

I'm trying to select rows from "mytable" based on a name/value pair.  For example, I'd like to select all rows that in their data field, have a name of "four" and a corresponding value less than .1.  (This should return rows 1 and 2).

I'd like to do this in one step. I realize I can denormalize the data and quite easily do it this way, but I'd prefer not to.  This operation will only happen on, at most, 500 rows, so I'm not terribly concerned with its performance.

For inputs $name and $value, I assume the solution would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 
  TO_INT(reg_ex(<crazyregex which selects $name>, data)) < $value
```

The problem is, I do not know the specifics of how to do this.

Hoping somebody can help.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there really no way other way to do regular expressions in MySQL other than a way which returns 1 or 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugly, but I think it works:

```
CREATE TABLE t (d varchar(255));

INSERT INTO t (d) VALUES
    ("one'.6332''two'.4231''three'.343''four'.034"),
    ("two'.4332''four'.033''five'.043"),
    ("four'.2323''seven'.3409''nine'.003"),
    ("four'.011''five'.043"),
    ("four'.100''seven'.3409''nine'.003")
;


SELECT
  d,
  convert(
    right(d, length(d) - instr(d, "four'")- 4),
    decimal(5,4)
  ) as v
FROM t
where d regexp "four'.0[0-9]*"
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I'm amazed there is no regular expression function in MySQL that returns a match rather than a 1 or 0.